# Simple text to speech with SAPI in a Windows Service

Tags: c++, sapi

Why does the following code fail after Speak() with error code 0x80045063 (SPERR_NOT_ACTIVE_SESSION) only when the process is running as a service?

```
ISpVoicePtr pVoice;
CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_SpVoice,
    0,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_ISpVoice, ( LPVOID * ) &pVoice
);

pVoice->SetOutput( 0, TRUE );
pVoice->Speak( L"Hello", 0, NULL );
```

The only resources I can come up with talk about security changes to services interacting with desktop sessions. The following in .NET will work within a service so I'm just curious as to how it would be accomplished using plain C++ with or without SAPI.

```
System::Speech::Synthesis::SpeechSynthesizer synth;
synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
synth.Speak( "Hello" );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAPI documentation lists `SPERR_NOT_ACTIVE_SESSION` as

> Neither audio output nor input is supported for non-active console sessions.

A service runs in a background session.  Due to [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) introduced in Vista, a service does not have access to Interactive resources, which includes Text-To-Speech.

Googling around, I found a couple of comments to back up that claim:

http://www.ip-symcon.de/en/service/documentation/module-reference/text-to-speech/tts-speak/

> This function does not work under Windows __ Vista/2003__ or newer. **This is because services such as IP-Symcon, for security reasons, can not access interactive components in the system. The Text To Speech output is such an interactive component**. The problem manifests itself with the error message: __ OLE error 80045063__ extract MSDN: **SPERR_NOT_ACTIVE_SESSION**.

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.tapi/2009-06/msg00003.html

> Note that they broke ( deliberately I think ) this stuff beginning on Vista (and later). **If you try to use SAPI's ISpMMSysAudio interface in a service (as they sketch in their bullet points in your link above), sooner or later you'll see a SPERR_NOT_ACTIVE_SESSION error.**

As for `SpeechSynthesizer`, my guess would be that it does not use SAPI internally.  The source code for `SpeechSynthesizer` is available here:

[SpeechSynthesizer.cs](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Speech/Src/Synthesis/SpeechSynthesizer@cs/1/SpeechSynthesizer@cs)

[VoiceSynthesis.cs](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/8@0@50727@4016/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Speech/Src/Internal/Synthesis/VoiceSynthesis@cs/1/VoiceSynthesis@cs)

Comment: I'll just use .NET and System.Speech as I don't think it's trivial otherwise. SAPI is used internally in Microsoft.Speech.